# how to populate dropdown selected value in textbox from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onchange

This is very common question but tried few things it didnt work. I am trying to fill textbox value from database according to value selected from dropdown.
my index.php

```
<?php
 # Connect 
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

# Choose a database
mysql_select_db('db_name') or die('Could not select database');

# Perform database query
$query = "SELECT * from customer_reg";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>whatever</title>
 </head>

<body>
  <label for="ddcust_nm">Customer Name: </label>
  <select id="customer_name">
   <option value="0">Please select</option>
   <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['customer_name'] . '</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>

<div>
  <label for="address">Street Address</label>
  <input id="address" name="address" class="element text large" type="text">
</div>

<div>
  <span class="floatLeft">
    <label for="phoneno">phone No:</label>
    <input id="phoneno" name="phoneno" class="element text medium" style="width:14em" type="text">
  </span>


</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function insertResults(json){
    $("#address").val(json["StreetAddress"]);
    $("#phone").val(json["City"]);

  }



  function makeAjaxRequest(placeId){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: { placeId: placeId },
      dataType: "json", 
      url: "search.php",
      success: function(json) {
        insertResults(json);
      }
    });
  }

  $("#customer_name").on("change", function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    if (id === "0"){
      clearForm();
    } else {
      makeAjaxRequest(id);
    }
  });
  </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Search.php

```
<?php
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('Could not connect: ' . 
mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('db_name') or die('Could not select database');

 $placeId = $_POST['placeId'];

  $query = "SELECT * from customer_reg";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($placeId == $row['id']){
     echo json_encode($row);
    }
  }
?>
```

I can get value from in dropdown, however , after selecting any value in dropdown nothing happens.
I tried alert in each function it doesnt show anything.
I tried click (I know I should not) , nothing fires
I got this code from [HERE](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/display-other-data-based-on-dropdown-selection/37679/2)

Please help

Comment: Have you checked your web browser console for any possible errors? I'm also not quite sure what "nothing happens" means. Something happens, but you may not be seeing it. Turn on full error reporting as well, add this to your script head: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: There is **no more support** for ``mysql_*`` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in PHP 7.0.0. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: @IncredibleHat an you please advise what should I change

Comment: You are returning html data and no need to encode in json, remove json_encode, just echo the result. Anyway as @Incredible say why you use mysql, its outdatet, use mysqli or pdo statement for more security.

Comment: You are also pulling ALL your data from the db table, and doing the 'search' inside the `while` loop. You would be better off putting the `$placeId` into a prepared statement to only pull one row from your database. Then `json_encode` that one row for your ajax success handler to use the fields as you wish.

Comment: @Sigma he is not returning html data, he is returning an array row of values (as json). Which he then tries to use (incorrectly) in `insertResults`. Where he has `$("#address").val(json["StreetAddress"]);` it should be more like `$("#address").val(json.StreetAddress);`.

Comment: :) In short, there are many many issues in this code, and all of which too numerous to cover in a single answer :(

Comment: @IncredibleHat let me fix this json and query issue , will let u know

Comment: @Sigma so should I replace mysql_query to mysqli_query?

Comment: Yes you should consider using msqli or pdo statements

Comment: @mark ... Inside the `insertResults()` function, do a `console.log(json)`...Let's see what you've got.